# Can we consider a supermarket as a market?

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, markets

Good morning,
I have been reading a book in which the author said that "the supermarket is not a market, because despit the large number of buyers, the seller is unique".

So, I've been wondering because according to me, even if the market has just a one seller, we can consider it as a market. Then, if we consider the competition on this market, there's only one seller and if we consider that this supermarket is the only one in a country, we could say that it's a monopolistic market (no competition).

What do you think ?

Comment: Definitions are flexible, and depends upon the context. If I were writing a text on trading in financial markets, a “monopolist market” would not qualify, as the mechanics of price determination is completely different. Since “market” is a word that pre-dates the discipline of economics, it will have flexible meanings.

Comment: A market is an abstraction where many buyers match with many sellers. A supermarket is a company that sells stuff to you. If Walmart is a market then Microsoft is a market - these are both nonsense. But there's a food market and an operating system market.